# Pandas multiindex boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, multi-index, booleanquery

So given a multiindexed dataframe, I would like to return only rows that satisfy a condition for all levels of the lower index in a multi index.  Here is a small working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'c': [0, 2, 2, 2]})
df = df.set_index(['a', 'b'])

print(df)
```

out:

```
     c
a b   
1 1  0
  2  2
2 3  2
  4  2
```

Now, I would like to return the entries for which `c > 1`.  For instance, I would like to do something like

```
df[df[c > 1]]
```

out:

```
     c
a b   
1 2  2
2 3  2
  4  2
```

But I want to get

out:

```
     c
a b   
2 3  2
  4  2
```

Any thoughts on how to do this in the most efficient way?

Comment: You mean c>1 and a=2?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to specify `a == 2`.  This is just a toy example.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? I don't see how what you are asking is not what you are getting with `df[df[c > 1]]`?

Comment: I want the `a` index to dominate, so if any of the entries under a unique value of `a`, in this case `a==2`, have a corresponding value of `c` such that `c>1`, then drop all entries associated to that value of the `a` index.

So, something like `df[df[c > 1 for all a == x] for all x in a] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: all([c > 1 for v in x['c']]))
```